# Что делает функция gluLookAt()?

Tags: c++, opengl

Что делает эта функция :

1) Изменяет координаты объектов, делая этим эффект камеры

2) Вращает именно "камеру", не меняя координаты объектов
???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двигает объекты.

По сути, в OpenGL "камера" фиксированная: на экран всегда попадает содержимое куба `[-1…1,-1…1,-1…1]` (+z - на наблюдателя, +x - вправо, +y - вверх).

Чтобы создать эффект подвижной камеры, нужно двигать объекты.